# Alfresco workflow activiti: How can I populate webservice result in dropdown

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am using Alfresco Community Edition-5.1.x , we created advanced workflow. In workflow we are trying to populate web-service results values in drop-down. Can you please guide us how to populate values in drop-down?

Answer (score 1):

On this sample code, I'm loading the group members into dropdown control by calling Alfresco Repo webscript.

Register the control here(in ftl file)

```
<label for="${fieldHtmlId}">${field.label?html}:<#if field.mandatory><span class="mandatory-indicator">${msg("form.required.fields.marker")}</span></#if></label>
<select name="${field.name}" id="${fieldHtmlId}" value="${field.value?html}" style="width: 250px;"></select>
```

Callback method once the data is received from the REST service

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     function ${grpName}_loadDropDown(o){          
        var selectElem = YAHOO.util.Dom.get("${fieldHtmlId}");
        selectElem.options.length=0;           
        for (; i<o.json.data.length; i++){           
            var user = o.json.data[i];                
            selectElem.options[j] = new Option(user.displayName, user.shortName, false, false);  
            j++;
        }            
     }
```

Call the REST service here

```
     function ${grpName}_loadData(){
        var url = Alfresco.constants.PROXY_URI+"api/groups/${grpName}/children?sortBy=displayName&maxItems=100&skipCount=0";             
        <#if field.control.params.sortAsc?exists> 
           <#assign sort=field.control.params.sortAsc?html>
           url+="&sortAsc=${sort}";
        </#if>
        Alfresco.util.Ajax.request({
        url: url,
          method: "GET",                 
           requestContentType: "application/json",    
            successCallback:{
           fn: function(o){
              ${grpName}_loadDropDown(o);              
           },
              scope: this                       
          },
          failureCallback:{
           fn: function(o){alert("Unable to find group or error ");},
           scope: this
          }               
      }); 
     }
```

Start the REST service request here

```
    ${grpName}_loadData();

  </script>
```

Comment: If REST API webservice , How we can you to populating drop-down list

Comment: This is also Alfresco's inbuilt REST API only (Alfresco.constants.PROXY_URI+"api/groups/${grpName}/children?sortBy=displayName&maxItems=100&skipCount=0";             )

Comment: But my web services external not alfresco inbuilt web services , how can i use external web services in alfresco and webservices result populating into drop-down list ,please help with refernces

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample for you and I've the following open JSON - RSET web services 
to get the data.

WebService URL : https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

The result should be something similar to the below one,[image]

Please let me know, if you need further help on this.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function ${groupName}_populateSelectData(o){
            var selectElem = YAHOO.util.Dom.get("${fieldHtmlId}");
            selectElem.options.length=0;
             var i = 0;
            var j = i+1;
            
            for (; i<o.json.length; i++){
                selectElem.options[j] = new Option(o.json[i].title, o.json[i].title, false, false);  
                j++;                   
            }
            
        }

function ${groupName}_updateList(){
            var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";   
             
            Alfresco.util.Ajax.request({
            url: url,
              method: "GET",    
             
               requestContentType: "application/json",    
              successCallback:{
               fn: function(o){
                  ${groupName}_populateSelectData(o);              
               },
                  scope: this                       
              },
              failureCallback:{
               fn: function(o){alert("Error ");},
               scope: this
              }               
          }); 
         }
      
      ${groupName}_updateList();
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i am able to use web-service and implemented in alfresco